# Hide main div, if child is empty

Tags: javascript, html, class, hide

I have this code:

```
<article class="ee-post ">
<div class="content">
<div class="image">
IMAGE
</div>
</div>      
</article>
```

I need simple JS, whose  will hide or delete class .ee-post, if .content is empty.
Function hide/delete if code seems this:

```
<article class="ee-post ">
<div class="content"></div>     
</article>
```

Thanks everyone for help

Comment: Is there a reason you are keeping the <article> tag and a <div> on the page? In my opinion it would be better removing that tag rather than just the <div class="image">

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `:has()` selector function for the parent; combined with the `:empty` selector for the child.

```css
.ee-post {
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 50px;
  border: thin dashed red;
}

.ee-post:has(> .content:empty) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<article class="ee-post">
<div class="content">
<div class="image">
IMAGE
</div>
</div>      
</article>

<article class="ee-post">
<div class="content"></div>     
</article>
```

If you want to use JavaScript, you can try the following:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.ee-post').forEach(post => {
  if (!post.querySelector('.content').hasChildNodes()) {
    post.classList.add('no-content');
  }
});
```

```css
.ee-post {
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 50px;
  border: thin dashed red;
}

.no-content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<article class="ee-post">
<div class="content">
<div class="image">
IMAGE
</div>
</div>      
</article>

<article class="ee-post">
<div class="content"></div>     
</article>
```

**Note:** You can modify the JS condition above, to add a guard for posts that do not have any `.content` child elements:

```js
if (!(post.querySelector('.content')?.hasChildNodes() ?? true)) {
  post.classList.add('no-content');
}
```

Comment: note that `:has` is relatively new and might not be a good solution for productive use.